# INSERT... SELECT-ом, а затем GetLastInsertID...

Tags: php, mysql

Продолжение темы.

В общем, добавляю новую строку в таблицу таким образом:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (f1,f2,f3,f4) 
SELECT 4,f2,f3,f4 FROM `table` WHERE f1=3;
```

После чего хочу получить `id (AUTOINCREMENT)` этой строки. Если вызвать просто `INSERT`, то `id` возвращает корректно, а если добавить `SELECT` к `INSERT`-у, то возвращает 0;

Что можно сделать и как получить последний `id`?

**РЕШЕНО**

В общем решил проблему так:

```
$db->Query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$row=$db->RowArray();
$id=$row[0];
```

Но все же, странно как-то всею Ну а если last-id не понадобиться в самом коде скрипта, то можно тупо в следующем запросе вызвать функцию last_insert_id(), как  я и сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `vizits` (`date`, `direction_id`, `empl_id`, `establishment_id`, `doctor_id`) SELECT `date`, `direction_id`, `empl_id`, `establishment_id`, `doctor_id` from `vizits` where empl_id=2;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Вроде возвращает не 0

Comment: Не знаю((( у меня ноль.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, точно ли добавляется запись, когда возвращается 0. Возможно, `select` возвращает пустой результат и `insert` не выполняется?

На каком столбце `primary key` и `auto_increment`?

Comment: Да, строка добавляется корерктно и `id` ему присваивается новая. `primary key` и `autoincrement` указаны на поле `id`.

Comment: Попробуйте явно прописать id и null

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, `autoincrement` работает, **если вставляем NULL**, иначе нет.

Пример из [How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

```
INSERT INTO foo (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');         # generate ID by inserting NULL
INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');  # use ID in second table
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, возвращается id, измененный последним запросом. Последний запрос - select, поэтому id = 0.
Дополнительно читайте [mysql-insert-id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

Comment: Как это последний запрос SELECT? Как он будет INSERT-тить, не получив SELECT-ом данные? Поэтому, логично полагать, что последний запрос, все таки, INSERT!